# The newBoston vid 21 list load but when click on list nothing happens

Tags: android, listactivity

I am new in android application development and using The New Boston tutorial. at lesson 21,when i run my code,everything is ok but when i click on lists activities not running!  .
Please help. I checked everything but i cant understand :(.

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test1.zip.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zip.test1.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Action"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zip.test1.ACTION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Test1Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zip.test1.TEST1ACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Menu.java

```
package test1.zip.com;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = { "Test1Activity", "Action", "Test1", "Test2" };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese = classes[position];
        try {

            Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.zip.test1." + cheese);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourclass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

logcat

```
11-03 05:52:24.744: D/AndroidRuntime(7191): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-03 05:52:24.744: D/AndroidRuntime(7191): CheckJNI is OFF
11-03 05:52:24.920: D/AndroidRuntime(7191): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-03 05:52:24.924: D/AndroidRuntime(7191): Shutting down VM
11-03 05:52:24.936: D/dalvikvm(7191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 72% free 294K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+2ms
11-03 05:52:24.936: D/dalvikvm(7191): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-03 05:52:24.948: I/AndroidRuntime(7191): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #1' failed
11-03 05:52:25.148: D/AndroidRuntime(7198): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-03 05:52:25.148: D/AndroidRuntime(7198): CheckJNI is OFF
11-03 05:52:25.349: D/AndroidRuntime(7198): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-03 05:52:25.356: I/ActivityManager(157): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=test1.zip.com/.Splash } from pid 7198
11-03 05:52:25.361: D/AndroidRuntime(7198): Shutting down VM
11-03 05:52:25.368: D/dalvikvm(7198): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 70% free 316K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+3ms
11-03 05:52:25.372: D/dalvikvm(7198): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-03 05:52:25.380: I/AndroidRuntime(7198): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #2' failed
11-03 05:52:33.905: W/System.err(7002): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zip.test1.Test1Activity
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at test1.zip.com.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:33)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-03 05:52:33.908: W/System.err(7002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-03 05:52:33.912: W/System.err(7002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 05:52:33.912: W/System.err(7002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-03 05:52:33.912: W/System.err(7002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-03 05:52:33.912: W/System.err(7002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-03 05:52:33.912: W/System.err(7002):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 05:52:33.912: W/System.err(7002): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.zip.test1.Test1Activity
11-03 05:52:33.912: W/System.err(7002):     ... 17 more
11-03 05:52:33.912: W/System.err(7002): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zip.test1.Test1Activity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/test1.zip.com-2.apk]
11-03 05:52:33.916: W/System.err(7002):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-03 05:52:33.916: W/System.err(7002):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-03 05:52:33.916: W/System.err(7002):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-03 05:52:33.916: W/System.err(7002):     ... 17 more
```

Test1Activity.java
    package test1.zip.com;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Test1Activity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

i think the problem is in this part

```
try {
              Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.zip.test1." + cheese);
              Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourclass);
              startActivity(ourIntent);
          }
          catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

i change to this and click on list works ! but ofcourse just go to action class.

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent("com.zip.test1.ACTION");
        startActivity(ourIntent);
```

Comment: use setOnItemClickListener method instead of onListItemClick

Comment: in video he used onListItemClick !

Comment: tried setOnItemClickListener , but its still same

Comment: I am sure : You must be getting then classNotFoundException please try to put some log inside catch method and check if it is hitting.

Comment: W/System.err(4127): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zip.test1.Test1Activity

Comment: Please put some log messages inside try and catch.And check is code running inside try block

Comment: Another thing in the manifest file you have only declared two activities.so Test1 and  Test 2 will not work.

Comment: @nomad im new in android i think that log cat

Comment: declared all activities in Android Manifest and then run this code.

Comment: @hrcj i put test 1&2 just for list test . i don't make any activity for them

Comment: Can You add the Test1Activity.java class.because it is showing class not found exception

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: @hrcj i added Test1Activity.java

Comment: Put this code  ------Log.e("Class",cheese ); add it bellow to "String cheese = classes[position]; "

Comment: I think that cheese variable is become null.

Comment: @hrcj
11-03 08:48:08.972: E/Class(1445): Test1Activity
11-03 08:48:10.348: E/Class(1445): Action

Comment: K next put Log.e("Class",ourclass ); below to "Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.zip.test1." + cheese);" and check the result

Comment: i got this error in class :

The method e(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class)

Comment: you can do one thing check.please add this one " Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,Test1Activity.java ); " instead of "Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourclass); "

Comment: @hrcj thanks alot freind . it fixed by replacing this ""com.zip.test1" with  this "test1.zip.com".

Comment: Ah cool.you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got this.The thing is in your manifest files you call the package.

```
 package="test1.zip.com"
```

But, in your activity part of the manifest you are trying to call

```
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zip.test1.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

so if you change all intent filters to start with

```
 "test1.zip.com"
```

instead of

```
"com.zip.test1"
```

it will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks you very very much @nomad. its now OK.why this happen???  i write just  exatcly like the video tutorial !

Comment: accept my answer pls use the green tick next to question

Comment: maybe you have copied and pasted some part wrong.but luckily it is solved;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all the String in the classes array to uppercase.
Aslo declare all your activities in the Manifest file, Test1 and Test2 are missing.

Comment: i changed to uppercase and delete tet1&2 but same error
11-03 06:39:59.881: W/System.err(9605): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zip.test1.TEST1ACTIVITY
11-03 06:40:15.536: W/System.err(9605): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zip.test1.ACTION

Comment: Also in your manifest remove the intent filters tag from Test1Activity and try to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

cast class like this

```
Class<?> c = null;  //<= this is what i say
if(StringClassname != null) {
try {
    c = Class.forName(StringClassname );
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
Intent intent = new Intent(mail.this, c);
startActivity(intent);
```